# Remove extra lines of vim and viminfo

Tags: linux, vim, command-line

I am making a cat with 2 files

1.txt content:

```
hi
```

2.txt content:

```
everyone
```

cat 2.txt >> 1.txt

1.txt new content:

```
hi
# This viminfo file was generated by Vim 7.2.
# You may edit it if you're careful!

# Value of 'encoding' when this file was written
*encoding=utf-8
...
everyone
```

It adds a lot of info that I don't want.

could you help me?

Regards.

Working on RHEL 6.4 64

Comment: Please describe your process in more detail. Because your problem is not reproducible as is.

Comment: I just edited vimrc file /etc/vimrc and added the next info: :set viminfo="".

Comment: Perhaps RHEL aliases cat?  (Sounds crazy, but it is the only thing I can think of.)  Try `cat --version` or `/bin/cat 2.txt >> 1.txt`.  What happens if you just try `cat 2.txt`?

Comment: To see the exact function of your `cat` command, check the output of `type cat`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the final file, just do

```
:g/^#/d
```

`g`   It is for Global

`^#`  It will find all the lines starting with #

`d`   It is for delete